# how do I write Pronto code into .wave file in android(Java)

Tags: java, android, wav

i am working to make remote functionality in android for example i have Pronto Hex Code

And I want to convert the above into wave file to and after converting I also want to play the wave file with Medial player

For example the above is to on the device and in my activity i have button and when i click to that button the audio is playing, and i have device which generates the signal when i connect that to my android phone on 3.5mm jack

here is a python code: http://rtfms.com/wp-content/rtfms-com/pronto_code_to_wav.py

Answer (score 1):

you check this link of remotecentral http://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/mboard/everything_else/thread.cgi?266
read from the fourth post you create wave file from Pronto hex code by using irp master library

Answer (score 0):

if you mean converting it to a infrared burst rate in this form {12,51,45,78,45,14}
just convert the hex code to decimal for example :
0000 0002 010d
should look like this
`int[] burst ={0,2,543}//the numbers is not correct just example`
and dont you forget the frequency.

Comment: No I have the hex file... I want to make a wav file out of my hex code